# Configuring Tomcat 8.5.16 to check CRL Distribution Points

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, java-security

Need to configure tomcat 8.5.16 to check CRL Distribution Points URL inside the provided certificate (.p12) and block revoked certificates.

After some investigation, I came up with the conclusion that tomcat checks the CRL URL automatically if the following properties are enabled:

```
 -Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true
 -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=true
```

I had achieved that behavior using tomcat 7, but with tomcat 8.5 seems that it's not working.

SSL Connector inside server.xml:

```
 <Connector
           port="9443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/mypageawthks.jks"
           keystorePass="Password1"
           truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/my_truststore.jks"
           truststorePass="mypass"
           clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Is there any way to check CRL Distribution Points automatically by tomcat 8.5.16?